# What is wrong on my localhost.5000 and my internal server?

Tags: reactjs, npm, localhost, react-scripts

I ran my old React js task on localhost:3000 and it worked but now when I try to run it on localhost:5000 it just shows the number 500 and says " a server error has occurred"(I installed the build folder by "npm run build" and the build folder has installed successfully. Then I run npm run-script build and npm run-script deploy, it shows me the `Local: http://localhost:5000` but when I enter the link, it just shows the number 500 and says "a server error has occurred").

This is the mistake on the console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Does anybody know what's wrong with my `localhost:5000`? Please help me.

Thank you so much

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-task-number",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.13.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-build-dist": "^0.0.8",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:dist": "react-build-dist",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "deploy": "serve -s build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: If the page is empty or blank, it means your app is being rendered but without it's content.  There might be something blocking it from being rendered.

Comment: I don't know. It works fine on localhost.3000 tho, when i try to open it other address it just doensn't work

Comment: i edited my question for some updates, please check out and help if you can! Thank you!